# value of org.neo4j.server.webserver.address

Tags: neo4j

I have two server in a LAN,A and B,I install neo4j on B,when I set

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address = 0.0.0.0
```

A can visit B:7474,but I set

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address = A
```

I get a error:

```
Failed to start Neo Server on port
```

how can I make sure only A can visit my db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to only allow a certain IP to use your server is to set

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address = 0.0.0.0
```

and use a local firewall to restrict access to port 7474 to the given clients (A in your example). Being on Linux you might use iptables for this, alternatively look at ufw.